# Querying Pandas with a Dictionary of Constraints

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am trying to pull out months within certain years with pandas. I have the constraints returned as such {month: year}.

```
 [{1: 2003},
 {2: 2008},
 {3: 2011},
 {4: 2012},
 {5: 2008},
 {6: 2008},
 {7: 2002},
 {8: 2006},
 {9: 2005},
 {10: 2013},
 {11: 2005},
 {12: 2001}]
```

Means I want January 2003, February 2008, etc. from the data frame. I have "Month" and "Year" as two columns in the data frame.

I want something that executes this incorrect code (but the idea is clear):

```
df[(df['Month'] == key for key in dict) & (df['Year'] == dict[key])]
```

Comment: is that how your dictionary looks like? you have actually pasted a list of dictionaries above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **lambda** to perform advanced filtering in Pandas.

**Assumptions:**

1. all month and year are integers
2. constraints are in `list of dict` type

You can modify the below lines to suite your problem if data types are different.

**Generate random data to fill data frame**

```
In [1]: from random import randint 

In [2]: months = [randint(1, 12) for x in range(10)]

In [3]: years = [randint(2000, 2020) for x in range(10)]

In [4]: months
Out[4]: [12, 3, 7, 6, 10, 10, 11, 9, 9, 10]

In [5]: years
Out[5]: [2017, 2016, 2001, 2004, 2015, 2013, 2001, 2020, 2013, 2016]

In [6]: import pandas as pd

In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame()

In [8]: df['Month'] = months

In [9]: df['Year'] = years
```

**2. Use the given `list of dict` and Convert it to `list of tuple` for easier coding**

(*Note: Once you understand what I am trying to accomplish, you may change your constraints as you wish.*)

```
In [10]: filterDict = [{1: 2003}, {2: 2008}, {3: 2011}, {4: 2012}, {5: 2008}, {6: 2008}, {7: 2002}, {8: 2006}, {9: 2005}, {3: 2016}, {6: 2004}, {12: 2001}]

In [11]: filterList = [d.items()[0] for d in filterDict]
```

**3. Use `lambda` to filter the dataframe**

```
In [12]: df[df.apply(lambda x: (x['Month'],x['Year']) in filterList, axis=1)]
Out[12]: 
   Month  Year
1      3  2016
3      6  2004
```

**Original Data before filtering for your reference:**

```
In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
   Month  Year
0     12  2017
1      3  2016
2      7  2001
3      6  2004
4     10  2015
5     10  2013
6     11  2001
7      9  2020
8      9  2013
9     10  2016
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from functools import reduce
df = pandas.DataFrame(dict(col1=[1,2], col2=['a','b']))
```

```
   col1 col2
0     1    a
1     2    b
```

```
params = dict(col1=2, col2='b')
mask = reduce(lambda x,y: x & y, [df[k] == v for k,v in params.items()])
print(df[mask])
```

```
   col1 col2
1     2    b
```

Answer (score 1):

One hack* to do this is to add up the year and month as a float and use that:

```
In [11]: months = set(year + month * 0.01 for i in d for (month, year) in i.items())

In [12]: months
Out[12]: {2001.12, 2002.07, 2003.01, 2005.09, 2006.08, 2005.11, 2008.02, 2008.05, 2008.06, 2011.03, 2012.04, 2013.1}
```

then check whether this same year.month is in the DataFrame:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame([[2001, 12], [2001, 3], [2002, 7]], columns=["Year", "Month"])

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
   Year  Month
0  2001     12
1  2001      3
2  2002      7

In [23]: (df["Year"] + 0.01 * df["Month"]).isin(months)
Out[23]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

so the subframe you want is:

```
In [24]: df[(df["Year"] + 0.01 * df["Month"]).isin(months)]
Out[24]:
   Year  Month
0  2001     12
2  2002      7
```

**It works but does feel a little dirty...*